# Check if operators are unitary equivalent

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

In my functional analysis class I was asked to check if these operators are unitary equivalent: multiplication operators in $L^2\left[-\pi,\pi\right]$ corresponding to functions $\sin t$ and $\dfrac t \pi$.

I know that unitary equivalent operators share the same norm and spectrum. And these operators have the same norm $\|A_1\|=\|A_2\|=1$ and spectrum $\sigma\left(A_1\right)=\sigma\left(A_2\right)=\left[-1,1\right]$. But it does not imply unitary equivalence. So what can I do next?

Thanks

---

I was asked to provide additional context. I'm familiar with the definition of cyclic vector, more over in my lecture notes there's

**Theorem** If $A=A^*$ has a cyclic vector than it is unitary equivalent to $A_t(x) (t)= tx(t) $ in $L^2(\sigma(A)) $ for some borel measure.

As a task was left the following statement: operators, multiplying by an argument are unitary equivalent iff corresponding measures are equivalent.

In my case theorem holds for both operators, but I have no idea how to check if measures equivalent.

Comment: These operators are not unitarily equivalent. The main reason is that the function $\sin t$ attains its values twice on the interval  $(-\pi,\pi]$ unlike the function $t/\pi.$

Comment: I find your question interesting and challenging. Provide in your post additional context and show what other methods, besides the comparison of the spectra, you know. For example are you familar with spectral resolution of the identity for a self-adjoint operators or the cyclic vectors of an operator ? Be fast as there are already $4$ votes  closing your post and in my opinion it would be a pity if it was closed.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $A_2$ admits a cyclic vector $f(x)\equiv 1.$ This follows from the Weierstrass theorem as $A_2^n1=t^n/\pi^n,$ and the polynomials are dense in $L^2(-\pi,\pi).$ On the other hand the operator $A_1$ does not admit a cyclic vector.
It is more convenient to consider the unitary equivalent operator $\tilde{A}_1$ acting by
$$(\tilde{A}_1f)(t)=\cos t\, f(t)$$
The operator $\tilde{A}_1$ does not admit a cyclic vector. Indeed, for $g\neq 0$
let $$h(t)=\begin{cases} \overline{g(-t)} & -\pi <t<0\\
-\overline{g(-t)} & 0<t<\pi
\end{cases}$$
Then
$$\langle \tilde{A}_1^ng,h\rangle = \int\limits_{-\pi}^0(\cos t)^ng(t){g(-t)}\,dt-\int\limits_0^\pi(\cos t)^ng(t){g(-t)}\,dt=0$$
Thus $g$ is not a cyclic vector.

Summarizing, the operators $A_1$ and $A_2$ are not unitarily equivalent.

**Remark** We could as well stay with the operator $A_1,$ but the definition of $h$ would be less transparent. We would have to define $h$ separately on $(-\pi,-\pi/2)\cup (0,\pi/2)$   and on $(-\pi/2,0)\cup (\pi/2,\pi).$

Comment: Wow, thanks! I did not suppose that we can such easily show non existence of cyclic vector. I have some more similar problems to practise, so I'm asking short advice for future: what key methods I can use in general case to check if operators unitary equivalent. It's enough to prove spectrums or norms are different, or existence and non-existence of cyclic vectors. To proof operators equivalent I can show theorem I cited holds for them. Are there any other useful ideas or methods?